When I try to build Build a ros1/moveit1 package that was originally built with kinetic on noetic I get an eigen error; "static assertion failed"
After running catkin_make with this package i get an eigen error:
[ 90%] Built target moveit_convert
/home/alex/robbi/src/moveo_moveit/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/alex/robbi/src/moveo_moveit/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp:126:47: warning: ‘using MoveItErrorCode = class moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode’ is deprecated: Use moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  126 |   moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode success = move_group.plan(my_plan);
      |                                               ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/alex/robbi/src/moveo_moveit/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h:64:7: note: declared here
   64 | using MoveItErrorCode [[deprecated("Use moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode")]] = moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:366,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Geometry:11,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/robot_model/joint_model.h:46,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/robot_model/joint_model_group.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h:48,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/noetic/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h:41,
                 from /home/alex/robbi/src/moveo_moveit/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>::Transform(const Eigen::Transform<_Scalar, Dim, OtherMode, OtherOptions>&) [with int OtherMode = 2; int OtherOptions = 0; _Scalar = double; int _Dim = 3; int _Mode = 1; int _Options = 0]’:
/home/alex/robbi/src/moveo_moveit/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp:65:95:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:331:25: error: static assertion failed: YOU_PERFORMED_AN_INVALID_TRANSFORMATION_CONVERSION
  331 |     EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(EIGEN_IMPLIES(OtherMode==int(Affine)||OtherMode==int(AffineCompact), Mode!=int(Isometry)),
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [moveo_moveit/CMakeFiles/move_group_1.dir/build.make:63: moveo_moveit/CMakeFiles/move_group_1.dir/src/move_group_interface_coor_1.cpp.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1236: moveo_moveit/CMakeFiles/move_group_1.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Fehler 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

but when building with ros kinetic it builds just fine. I have already ran rosdep so all necesarry packages are installed. does anyone know why I get this error and how I can fix it?
